#  custom calendar in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom calendar(Date for starting of the year is to be entered by the user).

For example,if a user sets date as 13th May, then his year must be set to 13-May to 12-May.Now I need to calculate the difference between 13th may and todays date(duration between 13th may- 24 sep)in number of days.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what has worked/not worked/looked promising?

Comment: @biddulph.r I have succeeded into my task into some extend. Now I want to get number of days passed between today and custom starting calender date.Modified the question for the same.

Answer (score 0):

visit following links to create custom calender

- http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/02/creating-custom-widget-calendar.html